# How do I make OS X say something when it finds the word "burning" in Console?

Tags: macos, console

How do I make OS X monitor the Console and say something when it finds the word "burning" in there?

Comment: What is the point of this? You can search the console for a keyword.

Comment: I can, but I want to be alerted when a specific entry appears, while I'm doing something else.

Answer (score 4):

Use the following command:

```
syslog -w|while read l;do [[ $l = *'burning'* ]]&&say the bush is on fire but was not consumed by the flames;done
```

`syslog -w` is a shorter alternative to `tail -f /var/log/system.log`. If you need another log use `tail -f /path/to/logfile` instead.